# Structure size definition

Tags: c++, memory, size, structure, allocation

Found a few similar posts but none that target my specific issue.

I'm trying to read a data structure from an external processes memory. I've used OpenProcess to get a handle, and my function for reading memory is pretty neat, but after assembling the first structure to be read, which should be 0xC0 bytes, I'm calling sizeof(structure) and getting double that value. The structure is below, if it helps. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

```
struct BattleListEntry
{
    int CID;
    wstring Name;
    byte* unknown[16];
    int z, y, x;
    byte* unknown2[8];
    int Direction;
    int TimeLastMoved;
    int rnd3, rnd4, rnd5, rnd6;
    int isWalking;
    byte* unknown3[12];
    int Outfit1, Outfit2, Outfit3, Outfit4, Outfit5;
    byte* unknown4[24];
    int HpPct; // 40 * 4 from start
    int rnd7;
    int rnd8;
    //byte* unknown5[12];
    int rnd9, rnd10, rnd11, rnd12, rnd13, rnd14, rnd15, rnd16, rnd17, rnd18;
};
```

Comment: Apologies, I may have extended the structure so that doubling the total size will actually get you the wrong value. Please ignore that mistake :)

Comment: You seem to believe that `byte* unknown[16]` is 16 bytes large. In fact, it's `16*sizeof(void*)` bytes large. It's not an array of bytes, it's an array of pointers. Also, `sizeof(wstring)` is very much implementation-dependent. What makes you believe the EXE in question was built with the same version of the same compiler as your program?

Comment: Nothing, but I've very carefully selected my variables to suit the sizes of the values to be read. The compiler used on the original program is made very obvious to be VS2010. I know that from my experience with reverse engineering the application before and after the release of VS2010, I've seen them accidentally implement ASLR, too... Pain in the butt that turned out to be. I sizeof'd wstring to confirm that it does in fact use 32 bytes. I realise that sizeof(byte) is actually 4, so after dividing those values, and a couple of other modifications I would be VERY close to the target...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Previous post is for you as well, but ran out of space. It looks like the byte arrays will be the issue, so I've fixed that now and I think I'm on the right track. Thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - If you post that byte* is the reason, I'll mark it as the answer for your brownie points. That really is the key to the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to believe that `byte* unknown[16]` is 16 bytes large. In fact, it's `16*sizeof(void*)` bytes large. It's not an array of bytes, it's an array of pointers.

Comment: Thanks again Igor, your help is largely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The types you use in the struct are not all fixed size. For example;

`byte* unknown[16];`

You can try minimizing the variant sized types and put them to the end and better use a label to declare their size.

Comment: Hi sgun, I believe wstring overflows into a pointer when it exceeds 32 bytes in a structure, as that's how it's operating in the target program and they are using a similar compiler to mine. Thanks for pointing out the byte* issue though, as Igor Tandetnik pointed out the pointers are the main cause of the issue. Thanks

Comment: False. The length of the actual text that a given `wstring` instance stores does not in any way affect the value of `sizeof(wstring)`, and consequently, the size of a structure that contains `wstring` as a member.

Comment: So you think that you can get the byte size of wstring by just using `sizeof(wstring)` ?

Comment: @sgun In VS2010 (and as far as I'm aware 2012) a wstring will fill with data, and if assigned more than 28 bytes of text, it will overflow into another memory location, and the last(?) 4 bytes of the original memory address will become a pointer to the new location. I'm not 100% of how it works, but that's my current understanding. The wstring in the structure is assigned only 28 bytes, therefore I will add the 4 bytes for the pointer and if they are non-null I can read them. I'll need to work out if it is 100% correct, but that's my current suspicion. Thanks again for your support

Comment: Please post your result here. I will check that too. I wonder if that's specific to VC++ or a general rule for c++.

Comment: OK, here is the result; size of wstring is fixed as Igor has pointed out. On my platform (linux) it's overflowing to other memory locations after 8th byte (one most probably a pointer to the new location). Not a suggested type in linux but a must on windows.